# Registering a class library within a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to instantiate a class from a third-party library from within a controller. Probably not the best place to do this but just testing.

```
require(craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'myplugin/vendor/ifpk/src/fsdk.php');

$app = new fSDK;
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Craft\fSDK' not found in /var/www/.../controllers/MyPluginController.php on line 57
```

Not sure where to go with this next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Through the magic of PHP namespacing, all plugins fall under the `Craft` parent class by default.

Since you're accessing a library outside of the `Craft` scope, you'll need to prepend a backslash to your library's class name:

```
$app = new \fSDK;
```